# Can I define a set in terms of itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

More specifically, what I want to define is the following set. Let $ A $, $ B $ be sets ,and $ G \subseteq A \times B $ be a set. Suppose the subscripts $ G_a = \{a \in A: \exists (a,b) \in G\} $ and similarly $ G_b = \{b \in B: \exists (a,b) \in G\} $. I want to define the following $ S = \{(a,b) \in A \times B: a \notin (S - \{(a, b)\})_a \land b \notin (S - \{(a, b)\})_b \} $. Is this, or anything that I did above, "illegal"?

**EDIT**

Sorry my notation is bad (learning this on my own as a hobby sort of thing). What I meant is that $ S_a $ is set of all $ a \in A $ where there is at least one $ (a,b) \in S $ and similar for $ S_b $.

**Clarification**

$ G_a = \{a \in A: \exists b(b \in B \land (a,b) \in G) \} $

$ G_b = \{b \in B: \exists a(a \in A \land (a,b) \in G) \} $

Maybe this is more what I had in mind.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. If anyone was wondering why I defining $ S $, I was using $ S $ to show that for sets $ A $ and $ B $, $ |A| \leq |B| $ or $ |B| \leq |A| $. I need to rethink how I am going to approach this now. But anyways, thank you all for the help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "let $S$ be a set with this property [where the symbol $S$ appears in several places]", but theres no guarantee that exactly one set $S$ satisfies that property (unless you can prove it), so it's not a definition.

Comment: The equation you wrote is confusing, though. Can you say in words what you're trying to define or give an example?

Comment: It looks like you're saying that in the directed graph representing $S$, every vertex has in-degree at most 1 and out-degree at most 1. Is that right?

Comment: Right off the bat, the equation $G_a = \{a \in A: \exists (a,b) \in G\}$ does not make sense. First of all, the $\exists$ sign is being misused; maybe just get rid of it. Also, on the left hand side $a$ is an unbound variable (a.k.a. a free variable), whereas on the right hand side $a$ is a bound variable. It would have made sense if you had written $G_b = \{a \in A : (a,b) \in G\}$;  now $b$ is an unbound variable, and $a$ is a bound variable, and there's no nonsensical $\exists$ symbol. This $G_b$ is the subset of all $a \in A$ which, when paired with $b$, give you an element $(a,b) \in G$.

Comment: @karl There definitely is not one set that fits my definition, but does that matter in the context of my proof? I only need one of them to exist anyway.

Comment: You can introduce a not-fully-specified object by giving it a name and describing a property it has, as in "Let $S$ be a set with the property that ....". This isn't considered a "definition" if you aren't uniquely identifying a set.

Comment: Your clarified versions of $G_a,G_b$ are closer to making sense, but it's somewhat confusing that your subscript letters are a literal part of the notation instead of variables (so e.g. your definitions apply to the expression "$X_a$" but not to "$X_c$"), especially since you've used the same letters as variables in the right-hand side. I'd define these as functions instead: $p_1(G)=\{a:(a,b)\in G\}$ and $p_2(G)=\{b:(a,b)\in G\}$.

Comment: Is it correct to say that you want to introduce a set $S\subseteq A\times B$ with the property that each element of $A$ occurs at most once as the first element of a pair in $S$ and each element of $B$ occurs at most once as the second element of a pair in $S$?

Comment: @Karl That is exactly what I want.

Comment: You could express that symbolically as: $\forall a\in A,|\{(x,y)\in S:x=a\}|\le 1$ and $\forall b\in B,|\{(x,y)\in S:y=b\}|\le 1$.

Comment: Or: $\forall a\in A,|(\{a\}\times B)\cap S|\le 1$ (and sim. for $B$).

Comment: A simple example where a set cannot be defined in terms of itself is $S=\{x\mid x\in S\}$. (Taken literally, this just states that $x\in S$ iff $x\in S$, which is true for _all_ $S$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Based on the clarification, you can define the sets $G_a$ and $G_b$ as follows:

$$G^{(1)}_a = \{ b \in B: (a,b) \in G\}$$
$$G^{(2)}_b = \{a \in A : (a,b) \in G\}$$
(a) Note that you must include in your notation something to tell the reader what coordinate you are considering (the superscript (1) and (2), in my notation). Consider, for example, what would be the definition of $G_2$? It is $\{ 2 \in A: (a,b) \in G\}$ or $\{ 2 \in B: (a,b) \in G\}$?

(b) A tip: You do not need to tell where $b$ came from because $(a,b) \in G$ already implies that $b \in B$.

2. Now, if understand correctly now, the set $S$ is such that if $(a,b) \in S$, there is no other element in $S$ with first coordinate $a$ or second coordinate $b$.

Again, it is not possible to define a set in that way.

Consider, for example, $A = B = \{0,1\}$. Imagine that you want to verify what elements belong to $S$. You will have:

$$ (0,0) \in S \implies (0,1), (1,0) \notin S$$
$$ (0,1) \in S \implies (0,0), (1,1) \notin S$$
$$ (1,0) \in S \implies (0,0), (1,1) \notin S$$
$$ (1,1) \in S \implies (1,0), (0,1) \notin S$$

Note that you cannot tell if $(0,0)$ belongs to  $S$ or not, because it depends if $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ belongs or not to $S$. The same thing occurs to every element of $A \times B$. For that reason, you can't define the set in that way.

As mentioned before, the way to work around this problem is by defying
a set property, which could be given by the following definition.

defition: Let $S \subset A \times B$. We say that the set $S$ is *foo* if, for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$:
$$(a,b) \in S \implies (a',b), (a,b') \notin S, \forall a' \in A, b' \in B,\, a'\neq a \text{ and } b' \neq b$$

Now, taking again that $A = B = \{0,1\}$, we have that the sets $S_1 = \{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ and $S_2 = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ have the *foo* property. note that this is yet another reason why you cannot define a set in the proposed way.

Comment: I get this, but can this property include $ S $ in its definition?

Comment: Sorry my notation is bad (learning this on my own as a hobby sort of thing), but what I meant to be the definition of the set does not imply the following. What I meant is that $ S_a $ is set of all $ a \in A $ where $ (a,b) \in S $ and similar for $ S_b $. If $ (0,0) \in S $ then you can't have any pair with $ 0 $s in them.

Comment: Your first and second equations makes the same mistake as the original post. In the notation $G^{(1)}_a = \{ a \in A: (a,b) \in G\}$, $a$ is a free variable on the left and a bound variable on the right. It would have made sense if the left hand side were $G^{(1)}_b$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thank you to point my mistake.  I will edit the post.